# PLSQL Multi string compare

Tags: oracle, syntax, plsql, comparison

I'm comparing several strings to a variable, example:

```
If (l_return != 'M') AND 
  (l_return != 'Y') AND 
  (l_return != 'W') AND 
  (l_return != 'D') AND 
  (l_return IS NOT NULL) then
```

I was wondering if it was possible to write a PLSQL compare statement like this:

```
if var in ('stringone', 'stringtwo', 'stringthree'):
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the syntax is like this:

```
If l_return not IN ('M','Y') then
    l_return := 'ERROR';
end if;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can. the same as you got `in` you can also do `not in`, like this :

```
If l_return not in ('M','Y','W','D') then
--code
end if;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another technique for single character string comparison is to:

```
if InStr('MYWD',l_return) > 0
  ...
```

Comment: And for multi-character strings, you'd need to include some kind of delimiter as well, e.g. `INSTR(':one:two:three:',':'||l_return||':') > 0`